# Render 22 millions of data points in interactive Graph in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, graph, render

I need to render around 22 million data points to interactive graphs in angular projects. Those data can be set as multiple graphs or multiple series. Currently, I tried with Highcharts though it also gives some problems with that amount of data. 
Can someone let what is the best way to render those kinds of data keep high performance and low lag? Are there any libraries that can be used to solve the above problem.